# How do I partition on saving parquet files with polars using Rust?

Tags: pandas, rust, rust-polars

So I was able to save some struct to Parquet file using the following code:

```
pub fn store(data: Vec<Data>) -> () {
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&data).unwrap();
    let cursor = Cursor::new(json);
    let mut df: DataFrame = JsonReader::new(cursor)
        .finish()
        .unwrap();


    let mut buffer = File::create("foo.txt").unwrap();
    let pw = ParquetWriter::new(buffer);
    pw.finish(&mut df);
    println!("{:?}", df)
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to partition based on columns? This feature is supported in pandas, you can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) where it is possible to pass `partition_cols` when calling the `to_parquet` function

Is this feature supported in polars?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a PartitionedWriter struct which does what you're asking

https://docs.rs/polars-io/latest/polars_io/partition/struct.PartitionedWriter.html

```
use polars_core::prelude::*;
use polars_io::ipc::IpcWriterOption;
use polars_io::partition::PartitionedWriter;

fn example(df: &mut DataFrame) -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let option = IpcWriterOption::default();
    PartitionedWriter::new(option, "./rootdir", ["a", "b"])
        .finish(df)
}
```

However it is only implemented for the IPC file format.  Looking at the implementation it would be quite simple to implement this for the ParquetWriter struct.

The IPC format may do what you need anyway since it is readable by PyArrow like so:

```
my_dataset = pyarrow.dataset.dataset('./root_dir/', format='ipc')
```